# I'm writing a telegram bot with python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to write a telegram bot via Python, but it doesn't work.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("my_token")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def sending(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


# RUN

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Returns to me the following problem.

> AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Comment: I'd suggest looking at [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) the wiki is great and full of code tips/features.

Answer (score 6):

This is a common issue, unfortunately. I guess you installed the lib as "pip install telebot", which leads to another package. You need to uninstall telebot, install `pytelegrambotapi`, but leave "import telebot" in code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. At first write:

```
pip3 uninstall telebot
```

After you do it write:

```
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI
```

And the last step:

```
pip3 install PyTelegramBotAPI==2.2.3
```

It worked for me, I'm working on debian 9. So if you are working on Debian or on linux, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As the [source code](https://github.com/KyleJamesWalker/telebot/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py) shows (assuming you import the module obtained from pip, that is [this](https://pypi.org/project/telebot/)), there is no definition for `message_handler`. In which case you need to use `@bot.route` which takes a string as argument as shown in the example within the repository readme (second link or [here](https://github.com/KyleJamesWalker/telebot)).

Example:

```
@bot.route('/command ?(.*)')
def sending(message, cmd):
    bot.send_message(something, something_else)
```

Comment: No other option?

Comment: That is the only function that handles incoming requests. Check the source code... it is one file and you can read everything that there is. There is really very little else. Many functions are not even implemented. Maybe check the forks as they may have more features (the forks need to be downloaded typing the git address manually https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git ).