# 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

When I run the code below the following error message is displayed: `'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'`.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard1.row('Ok', 'Bye')

bot = telebot.TeleBot('API')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi what do you want /start', reply_markup=keyboard1)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() =='Hello':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text.upper() )
    elif message.text.lower() =='Bye':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'see you soom' )
    elif message.text.lower() == 'I love you':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'API')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def sticker_id(message):
    print(message)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

So what is wrong? I have installed pip and others. I wrote it on python IDLE. I wanted to make a telegram bot which gives stickers.

Answer (score 15):

Try this code:

```
pip3 uninstall telebot
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install --upgrade pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Answer (score 6):

I did

```
pip3 uninstall telebot
```

Then

```
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI
```

And then

```
pip3 install PyTelegramBotAPI==2.2.3
```

And it works now!

PyTelegramBotAPI 3.0 have lot of changes and 3.0 API docs are not there yet. WIP. Use 2.2.3 older version instead and make sure you don't have any other bot api like telebot

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a versioning issue.  I did a little googling (which you should have done before asking this here), and came up with many instances of this error message.  Most of them point to the use of the wrong version of the `PyTelegramBotAPI` module. Here's a post from someone with seemingly the exact same issue you are having:
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/26658/

There are other hits that suggest the same sort of fix.  There' also this SO question: [I'm writing a telegram bot with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909321/im-writing-a-telegram-bot-with-python)

which seems to go a different route towards solving your problem.

For more information, just google the title of this question.

Comment: I changed message_handler to 
@bot.route('/command ?(.*)')
def sending(message, cmd):
    bot.send_message(something, something_else)
and now it says 
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'polling'

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, try after installing below command:

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Note: if you have installed any other packages for `import telebot` then uninstall those and try after that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote 'import PyTelegramBotAPI'
then imported this by click in intellij idea
after that replaced 'PyTelegramBotAPI' with 'telebot' -> 'import telebot'

super crutches

Answer (score 0):

Wasted a whole hour trying to solve the problem. Other possible variant which worked for me:

With latest (4.2.2) TeleBot version, it didn't work without explicitly specifying some arguments. Like:

`bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, logger_level=logging.DEBUG)`

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me its launching .py directly from file not from cmd

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

What helped me in this situation: you have to define your token as a string. Like that:

```
API_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxx'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
```

But not like that:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxxxxxx')
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```py
pip3 uninstall pytelegrambotapi
pip3 install pytelegrambotapi
```

Thanks to:

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/341#issuecomment-302945129

Comment: Lil_Homer, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: Sorry. Already changed. Thanks for the comment.